# Normalize data using temporary table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I have a table with weights that I want to renormalize in MySQL.  I'm getting a "Can't reopen table" error when I attempt to join it to an inline query that relies on itself, and the same error when I attempt to use a CTE.  Table sample below:

**weights**

```
monthEnd, portName, ticker, wgt
2019-04-30, test, MTUM, 0.20451060987312306
2019-04-30, test, SIZE, 0.20763723114425484
2019-04-30, test, USMV, 0.2043537465059284
2019-04-30, test, QUAL, 0.20758892877605561
2019-04-30, test, VLUE, 0.20683696239330326
```

I would like to do something like the following to renormalize the `wgt` column (ie, sum(wgt)=1):

```
select a.monthEnd, ticker, wgt/totWgt 
from weights a
inner join ( 
            select monthEnd, sum(wgt) as totWgt
            from weights
            group by monthEnd ) tot
            on a.monthEnd = tot.monthEnd
```

But I get an error message indicating:

```
Error Code: 1137. Can't reopen table: 'a'
```

I get the same message when trying to do this using a CTE instead of a temporary table, and this appears to be a [known issue within MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html).

Insofar as I need the **weights** table to calculate the total weight, the only way what I'm trying to do appears possible is to create yet *another* temporary table to hold the total weight and join my **weights** table to it to do the normalization.

Is there a better way to do this in MySQL 8.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL only allows you to have one reference to a temporary table.  You *could* copy the table over.  However, window functions are a simpler solution:

```
select monthEnd, ticker, wgt / sum(wgt) over (partition by monthEnd) 
from weights w
```

Comment: you're a champ, this appears to work.  Never seen this before, what's the relationship between the use of OVER here versus GROUP BY?

Comment: @Chris . . . https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html.